# Joining tuples within a list without converting them to Str

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to create the Mysql Insert query like this for inserting million of records:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (fee, fi) VALUES 
   ('data1',96)
  ,('data2',33)
  ,('boot',17)
```

My values is stored as tuple in the list:

```
datatuplst = [("data1",96), ("data2", 33),("data3", 17)]
```

My code:

```
c3 = con.cursor()
c3.execute("INSERT INTO `bigdataloadin` (`block_key`, `id`) VALUES %s" %','.join(datatuplst))
```

This is not working and I'm getting error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Need help on how to create the dynamic query with values stored in tuples list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the string that you need. The error is explanatory enough. When it is `','.join(datatuplst)` the interpreter is forced to join tuples. So using list comprehension you can say this instead:

```
','.join([str(el) for el in datatuplst])
```

The output for this statement is going to be: `"('data1', 96),('data2', 33),('data3', 17)"`

Then your actual INSERT statement will be interpreted as follows:

```
"INSERT INTO `bigdataloadin` (`block_key`, `id`) VALUES ('data1', 96),
('data2', 33),('data3', 17)"
```

Good luck!